# MySQL Json extract Multiple Array Object

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I have have Json data stored in Json type field in MySql 5.7.
Here is my Json data structure:

```
{
"111" :[
  {
    "id"   : 1,
    "name" : "John",
    "age"  : 31,
    "group": 111
  },
  {
    "id"   : 2,
    "name" : "Paul",
    "age"  : 30,
    "group": 111
  },
],
"222" :[
  {
    "id"   : 3,
    "name" : "Jack",
    "age"  : 31,
    "group": 222
  },
  {
    "id"   : 4,
    "name" : "Robin",
    "age"  : 30,
    "group": 222
  },
]
}
```

and i want to extract the data as a table-like structure with MySql statement. The idea is  to get like this :
[image]

i already try this

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(jsonData -> '$."111"', '$[0]."name"') as name from table_t
```

but it just extract per key and index.

Please help,

Thank you

Comment: The [JSON_TABLE() function in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) would make this possible, though it would still be awkward. If you're stuck on MySQL 5.7, I strongly suggest you store your data in normal rows and columns, and do not store the data in JSON documents, if you want the result you describe.

Comment: I do agree with you, i'd like to have it in normal rows and columns, but unfortunately it's not depends on me.

Comment: Then I would recommend fetching the whole JSON document into your application, and write code to sort out the fields you want.